# Decomposable set definition

Tags: real-analysis

I have troubles with finding the definition of "decomposable set". Does anybody know a definition or where I can find one?

Comment: If you google this term you get https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Decomposable_Set Does it answer your quesiton?

Comment: I was looking for a definition for a set in a function space such that $L^1$; the definition should involve characteristic functions and stuff like that.